# Apache not starting in linux mint

Tags: apache, configuration, linux-mint

Ok, so, I'm fairly new to Apache: I was trying to create a local website (created the .conf file in sites-available folder, created the folder in var/www/mysite/ etc.) then, I stopped Apache (with **systemctl stop apache2.service**) but now if I try to restart (**systemctl restart apache2.service**) it throws this error:

> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with >error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

This is the result of journalctl -xe:

```
Mar 22 16:33:13 user-xxx apache2[10403]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apach
Mar 22 16:33:13 user-xxx apache2[10403]:  *
Mar 22 16:33:13 user-xxx apache2[10403]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Mar 22 16:33:13 user-xxx apache2[10403]: Output of config test was:
Mar 22 16:33:13 user-xxx apache2[10403]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Mar 22 16:33:13 user-xxx apache2[10403]: Action 'configtest' failed.
```

And the line 140 in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load <--This one
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
```

So I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

And I get:

```
libapache2-mod-php is already the newest version (1:7.2+60+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
```

What else I tried: removing Apache and installing again, installing lamp (sudo apt-get install lamp-server^). 
I already removed: mysite.conf from available.sites ...

Nothing seems to make it work, I keep getting "Job for apache2.service failed".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, kind of a dumb error, I ran **apachectl configtest** to get more detailed error and I got:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax 
error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load: Cannot load 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so into server: 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

So I checked **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load** and at line 3 it had:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so
```

But in my **/usr/lib/apache2/modules** folder I had a newer module:

```
libphp7.2.so
```

So In **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load** I changed it to:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
```

Then restarted apache and it's working like a charm!!!.

Note: I don't know if this is the correct way to do this but, it's working.

Comment: In my case, I found only `libphp7.3.so`.

Comment: Correct way to fix this is Audrius' solution below.

Answer (score 21):

after ubuntu update to 20.04 I changed PHP to 7.4

```
sudo a2dismod php7.3
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo apachectl configtest
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: 7.4 to 8.1 in my case, thanks

Answer (score 6):

In my case failure happened when upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Module libphp7.2.so instead of libphp7.4.so was loaded in conf file Melesio Marquez's solution worked!

Answer (score 5):

I faced the error:

> Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/

after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 (php 7.3 to php 7.4)

I solved it by running

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.4
```

Comment: this is life saving

Answer (score 2):

You can check your PHP version from here ->

```
php -v
```

then write this command

```
sudo a2dismod php7.3
```

You should see that Module `php7.3` disabled.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

If you want to sure check your confs

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

You should see (Syntax OK)
and finally, restart your apache server (`sudo systemctl restart apache2`)

Answer (score 0):

The files in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ are symlinks to /etc/apache2/mods-available/*
So just remove them and create new ones. To create a symlink at /usr/bin/bar which references the original file /opt/foo, use: ln -s /opt/foo /usr/bin/bar

To fix

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
rm php7.*
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.4.load php7.4.load
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.4.conf php7.4.conf
```

Make sure the files exist and the old links are removed. Editing the symlinks will result in upgrade issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I used a variation of this solution where I just went into `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` and symbolically linked
`../mods-available/php8.1.load` to `php8.1.load`
and
`../mods-available/php8.1.conf` to `php8.1.conf`.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.3.load: 
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.3.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.3.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Updated /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.3.load to point to libphp7.4.so:

```
#LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.3.so
LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so
```

Comment: Hi @eugho, welcome to Stackoverflow! It's great that you want to contribute and share your knowledge. Please note: Before answering, please read the question carefully. You will notice that the original poster has a completely different error than you describe in your answer. Your error is "No such file or directory" while their error is "Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf". (Not trying to be a dick here, just trying to help you improve).

Comment: Hi @Stefan, please take a look at the answer given by the poster himself. He did add-on with additional error logs that matches the errors I have provided.

Comment: Hi @eugho, sorry, the Stackoverflows review-UI only asked me to review your answer, so I didn't see anything else. :) In any case, I would really ask you to make yourself familiar with the posting-guidelines for good answers:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer -- Which category do you think your answer falls into? :) -- Stay safe!